# Unwanted white space to the right on Mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm learning to develop a website called [icoined.com](http://icoined.com/) and now I am running into a problem with unwanted white space to the right side of the mobile screens which I can't figure out what cause it. I'm new to this so please ELI5. Thanks.

Comment: Post your CSS. From what I can see, your site looks great on the first load. The problem happens when the screen is turned on landscape side, then back to portait. Your problem is certainly in your `@media screen and (orientation:portrait)` part.

Comment: And in the console (on pc), you have an error which may be related: `Failed to parse SourceMap: http://icoined.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css.map`

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the class `img-responsive` to the image with the source `assets/img/ico.png`.
2. **Also**, In my tests I replaced your bootstrap version with this:

   ```
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   ```

   and it's working perfect (You can see it in this [bin](http://jsbin.com/tisazo/edit?html,js) - you can try to run it with or without your css which is in comment in that bin).

Comment: And 1 more thing the container `padding-right` also affecting the layout.

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr I can't see that class (`.padding-right`) in his code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: Now I'm kinda running into another problem though. There's still a little bit of white space left and I think the nav-bar caused it? And the text doesn't line up on ipad

Comment: It's deep work bro, You need to try and fail until you will find. Sorry but I have no time to do this for you..